# Unity AudioSource unable to play clip

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to play a sound when a user drags a 2D gameobject.

The gameobject will have to play many sounds, so I am programmatically creating Audio Sources and assigning clips through the inspector.

```
public class Card: Monobehavior, IDraggable {
    public AudioClip tokenGrabClip;
    public AudioClip tokenReleaseClip;

    public AudioSource tokenGrab;
    public AudioSource tokenRelease;

    public AudioSource TokenGrab {
      get{ return tokenGrab; }
    }


    public virtual void Start() {
      tokenGrab = AddAudio (tokenGrabClip, false, false, 1f);
      tokenRelease = AddAudio (tokenReleaseClip, false, false, 1f);
   }

    public virtual AudioSource AddAudio(AudioClip clip, bool isLoop, bool isPlayAwake, float vol) {
    AudioSource newAudio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    newAudio.clip = clip;
    newAudio.loop = isLoop;
    newAudio.playOnAwake = isPlayAwake;
    newAudio.volume = vol;
    return newAudio;
  }
}
```

This will create two audio sources for every gameobject of type `Card` in my game.

Now in my game manager, I simply try to play a sound...

```
void CheckDragStart(GameObject go, Draggable d) {


    if (go.GetComponent<Card> () != null) {
        print("check drag start");
        go.GetComponent<Card> ().TokenGrab.Play ();

    }
}
```

No sound is played, but I am able to to see my console with the "check drag start message".

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I can see audio sources assigned to my game objects with my methods in the first code block, but my audio clips are not being assigned to them...

Comment: I'd recommend putting the inspector into debug mode (shows more values), then calling `Debug.Break()` immediately after calling `TokenGrab.Play()`. That will pause the editor at the end of that frame, so that you can inspect the AudioSource and confirm that all fields are as expected. It may be that it's "playing" but inaudible, which is a whole different set of problems to troubleshoot.

Comment: @rutter

After digging around and getting a second set of eyes on my code, we figured out that we simply did not update our card prefabs...The solution came to loading audio clips in Awake, and then audio sources in start so that it all sounds can be applied to every card prefab. Thank you for reminding about Debug.Break(), I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be that *go* GameObject, `GetComponent<Card>()` or `TokenGrab` is `null`. If any of them is null, you will get the `NullException` error. I am ruling those out.

Looking at your code, these are the possible reasons why your audio is not playing. Ordered from very likely to least.

**1**.Your `AudioClip` is not assigned from the Editor.

Check that both of these variables are assigned fom the Editor.

```
public AudioClip tokenGrabClip;
public AudioClip tokenReleaseClip;
```

This must be done for *each* `Card` script that is attached to any GameObject in the scene.

You **won't** get any error if they are not assigned or null. It simply **won't** play.

**2**.Your `Card` script and the GameObject it is attached to is destroyed after `Play()` is called. Try to comment anywhere you have the [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) function. Try it again. If problem is solved you have to fix that by moving your AudioSource to an empty GameObject that does not need to be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I am just putting up my suggestion here. I see that you don't want to loop the clips. So why don't you try something like this?

```
public AudioClip tokenGrabClip;
public AudioClip tokenReleaseClip;

AudioSource      audioSrc;

void Start () {

    audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
}

public void PlayTokenGrabClip () {

    audioSrc.PlayOneShot (tokenGrabClip);
}

public void PlayTokenReleaseClip () {

    audioSrc.PlayOneShot (tokenReleaseClip);
}
```

Add an `AudioSource` component to your `GameObject`. Assign the audio files (`mp3`, `wav`) to `tokenGranClip` and `tokenReleaseClip` through the editor. Then call the functions `PlayTokenGrabClip ()` and `PlayTokenReleaseClip ()` to play the respective sounds as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from not updating my prefabs. I was assigning AudioClips in my C# script publicly, however, this change was not immediately reflected in my prefabs. Rather than having to update many prefabs, I reorganized how my resources load on startup:

I define my audio clips with `Resources.Load(...) as AudioClip;` in `Awake()` and create AudioSource Components in `Start()`. From this, I am able to add AudioClips to my AudioSources via C#.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Card : MonoBehaviour, IDraggable {



    public bool counter;

    private AudioClip tokenGrabClip;
    private AudioClip tokenReleaseClip;

    private AudioSource tokenGrab;
    private AudioSource tokenRelease;

    public AudioSource TokenGrab {
        get{ return tokenGrab; }
    }
    public AudioSource TokenRelease {
        get{ return tokenRelease; }
    }


    public virtual void Start() {
        tokenGrab = AddAudio (tokenGrabClip, false, false, 0.5f);
        tokenRelease = AddAudio (tokenReleaseClip, false, false, 0.5f);
    }

    public virtual void Awake () {
        tokenGrabClip = Resources.Load ("Audio/tokenGrab") as AudioClip;
        tokenReleaseClip = Resources.Load ("Audio/tokenRelease") as AudioClip;
    }


    public virtual AudioSource AddAudio(AudioClip clip, bool isLoop, bool isPlayAwake, float vol) {
        AudioSource newAudio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource> () as AudioSource;
        newAudio.clip = clip;
        newAudio.loop = isLoop;
        newAudio.playOnAwake = isPlayAwake;
        newAudio.volume = vol;
        return newAudio;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is a problem described in my #1 solution.